# Extjs implementing stores beyond basic CRUD

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs-stores

I'm facing a situation while implementing serverside functionality with extjs.
The problem is that I need to get data from serverside say a filesystem.. Im not storing the file system in some database so I don't have any "id" field to begin with.
Then there a multiple operations that a user can do with the nodes (files or directories) in the file system.
Like renaming, deleting, adding new file, adding new directory, changing the contents of a file, copying a file, moving a file.
And for all this the basic CRUD functionality provided by the Extjs stores.api isn't just enough.
So is there a way to extend the functionality of the api or the stores itself?

OR any suggestions on changing the architecture?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should be looking at is the Proxies (such as Ext.data.proxy.Proxy), not the stores. For example, you could look at creating a custom proxy that extends WebProxy (if WebProxy has some of the functionality you're looking for).

Another idea would be to expose all of the actions that you need to do on the server via webservices, and then you could use the extjs implementation of the ajax proxy to trigger these actions when you need it to.